# How to make a hole in an image iphone

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, cocos2d-iphone, uiimage

I have a game that players place their pieces on the screen then press set. I am using cocos 2d to build the iphone app. It is kind of like hide and seek. I then overlay a background on top of all of that. I want to be able to tap on the screen and create a hole in my background at that spot so that I can see through it. I know I can just create a giant image with a hole in it and move it around, but my background can only be a color it can't be an image. How should I go about doing this.

Comment: I've had limited success with image masks in ios (via Quartz 2D). Might be something to look into.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of trying to see "through" the overlay, place the "background" image on top in circles.  Map the screen coordinates on top of the "background" image, then extract a circular region from that image to place on the screen.  The biggest challenge would be capturing a circular region from your bitmap.  I'm not too familiar with cocos2d, but there should be a library you can use for it.